# Separately called React setState() giving unexpected result

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new with React and confused with the result below code is giving.
`num` gets value -1, where I think it should be 100.

`useEffect[num]` is expected to run first, calling `setNum(100)` since `num` is initialized to -1.
Then `useEffect[dummy]` will run, calling `setNum(-1)`.

I learned that multiple calls to the same `setState` function are **batched** together, and only the result from the last call is rendered.

So it seems like `setNum(100)` will be overwritten by subsequent `setNum(-1)`.

The problem is, if `setNum(-1)` was processed in the end, it should have called `setNum(100)` in `useEffect[num]`.
`num` should be 100, but it's stuck at -1.

Why did my program stop before calling `setNum(100)` in the end?
Please teach me what I'm missing : async nature of setState or batched updates?

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(-1);
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setNum : ", num);
    if (num === -1) setNum(100);
  }, [num]);

  // Just to call setNum(-1) separately
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Init dummy : ", dummy);
    setNum(-1);
  }, [dummy]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> {num} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is codesandbox to run the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-chatelet-3oxy8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, if setNum(-1) was processed in the end, it should have
> called setNum(100) in useEffect[num].

Here's how your code executes:

1. Initial render of the component
2. First `useEffect` is called; it logs the value of `num` and then calls `setNum(100)`
3. Second `useEffect` is called which logs the value of `dummy` and then calls `setNum(-1)`
4. There are two pending `num` state updates; both of them are batched and the last one wins, i.e. `setNum(-1)`.
5. Component re-renders and the value of `num` is `-1` BUT that won't trigger the first `useEffect`, even though it depends on `num`, because the **value of `num` didn't change; it's still `-1`**

If you change the initial value of `num` to any value other than `-1`, you will see the first `useEffect` executing again like you expect.

Comment: I am thinking that you explain my answer in detail and got the vote, xDD

Answer (score 1):

If you switch the useEffects like this:

```
      // Just to call setNum(-1) separately
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Init dummy : ", dummy);
        setNum(-1);
      }, [dummy]);

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("setNum : ", num);
        if (num === -1) setNum(100);
      }, [num]);
```

The final num should be 100.

Comment: So in this case, 
useEffect[dummy] calls setNum(-1) → useEffect[num] calls setNum(100)  

And last call 'setNum(100)' wins from batching

Answer (score 1):

In the `useEffect` order matters and the `initial value` also.

If the initial value and settled value are the same then no `rerender` will execute and your dependency useEffect also not called and your final value will be your initial value.

```
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(-1);
  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("setNum : ", num);
    if (num === -2) setNum(100);
  }, [num]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Init dummy : ", dummy);
    setNum(-2);
  }, [dummy]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div> {num} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, if you will add `-2` in the if and your `dummy` useEffect then you will see your desire result `100`.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-blackwell-odl5v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: So if setState does not change the state, useEffect will not be called (neither rendering happens). Seems pretty obvious after reading this. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes you are right, only the state can perform rerender, I am happy that you solved your confussion